# Изменить прототип ячейки таблицы

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Возможно ли изменить прототип ячейки таблицы (перезагрузить таблицу) в iOS после загрузки таблицы и показа её на view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, конечно, для этого достаточно создать второе представление для отображения ячейки, например SecondTableViewCell. Зарегистрировать ячейку с ключом отличным от первой ячейки и в методе cellForRow(at:) сконфигурировать ячейку. Либо напрямую в cellForRow создавать свою ячейку.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell
if(condition)
{
  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "iden_1", for: indexPath)
  let stats = fetchedResultController.object(at: indexPath) as! Stats
  cell.textLabel?.text = stats.type
  cell.detailTextLabel!.text = stats.name
}
else{
  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "iden_2", for: indexPath)
  let stats = fetchedResultController.object(at: indexPath) as! Stats
  cell.textLabel?.text = stats.type
  cell.detailTextLabel!.text = stats.name
}


return cell
}
```

Comment: Как я понял это сработает только перед отображением таблицы на экране. А если таблица с ячейкой уже показана на экране и тут пришли некоторые данные которые должны быть показаны на другом прототипе ячейки, но в этой же таблице? Можно ли заменить прототип ячейки «на ходу»?

Comment: Вы можете удалить/добавить ячейку и сделать перезагрузку таблицы reloadData()

Comment: Спасибо. Что-то не подумал об этом. Завтра попробую.

Comment: Нет, не работает. В принципе это уже не нужно. Вопрос закрываю. Но все равно спасибо.